# z-index doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I am having some issues with z-index in bootstrap.

I had to adjust the z-index of my hero unit so that my drop down menu would go over it.  In doing so, my Action Button appears to now be in the background and is unclickable...I tried changing the z-index of the action button, but that dos nothing.  Removing it from the Hero Unit and placing it underneath allows it to be clickable, but the hero unit disappears.

Not sure if there is any recommendations you could give?  Thank you!

Page Sample: http://test.saviodesigns.com/ecs/services.php

Code Section:
    
  
  
  Click to Book an Appointment!

CSS:

```
#hero2 {
margin-top:0;
background:#000 url(../img/header-image2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
position: relative;
background-size: contain;
width: 100%;
z-index:-1;
}

#action-bar {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.61);
margin-top: 220px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Why did you add z-index:-1 to your hero ID ?
Remove that, and the button would work perfectly.

Comment: yes. remove the z-index:-1 for #hero2 and "click to book an appointment" button will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! I added the z-index to the hero when I added it to the menu to try and make them play nice together - thinking I needed it on the hero.  Your suggestions of removing it from the hero (leaving it only on the menu) worked! I appreciate your help!